# Customers ACL (extension or tips)

Tags: access, acl

I'm looking for a solution to manage read/write access on backend customers area.

Some users need to be able to view the customers détails & create/edit customers data. But others (different user role) should be able to view only.

I've already see an extension dedicated to my requirement: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/manage-customer-acl.html
But it is an alpha stability state, and the installation through Mage Connect is stopped because of Php 5.4.12 incompatibility.

Is someone have an idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried to search magento connect for "advanced permissions"?

Comment: Amasty, your extension seems very powerfull, regarding Products Access Levels Rights requirements. But, I've not read any informations about the capability of define read only role access to the "Customers management". Can you tell me if your extension provide that kind of feature?

Comment: There are several advanced permissions modules at the magento connect. If you like ours ( personally i glad to hear it) , please contact us directly, as this site is not for advertising own content.

Comment: Sure, I'll give it a try. But although I found that several ACL modules exist, anyone provide what I need (customers read/write).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular module http://amasty.com/magento-advanced-permissions.html   allows to restrict "save" action for products and customers, so enables "read-only" access.

If you know any other, feel free to add them as well.

Comment: Thanks for this answer but unfortunately we don't want advertisement here :-/

Comment: It's my fault :(